# port bound by docker on boot, but not containers running

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-machine

I'm running ubuntu 18.
I have an app that listens on port 10010.
However it seems that since a few boots ago, docker is bound to that port.

```
dory@machine:~ $ sudo netstat -plnt | grep 10010
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.165:10010     0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1753/docker-contain
```

running docker ps gives me nothing:

```
dory@machine:~ $ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
```

kiling the process just makes it re-launch.
rebooting the machine also triggers that again.
How can I find what it causing this to launch?
How can I disable this?
What is this?

Comment: Is your docker command talking to the local docker install (`echo $DOCKER_HOST`)? Is this node a member of a docker swarm?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a newer version of Docker (versions that are meant to support Kubernetes natively, specifically v18.03+), then that is the CRI streaming server. Newer versions of containerd now contain the CRI plugin, which is enabled by default.

There is work being done to [add an option for disabling it](https://github.com/moby/moby/pull/37519), or to [disable it by default](https://github.com/docker/engine/pull/29), but for now to free up the network port you'll need to downgrade Docker to v18.03. You could also disable the CRI plugin in the containerd configuration file (`/var/run/docker/containerd/containerd.toml`), but it's autogenerated by Docker, so your changes will not persist.

More information can be found in the issues [moby#37507](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/37507), [containerd#2483](https://github.com/containerd/containerd/issues/2483), as well as the merged PR for the config option at [moby#37519](https://github.com/moby/moby/pull/37519).